# Redis error on start: invalid bind address

Tags: redis

I am seeing in the following in my `redis` log:

```
[1398] 17 Jun 22:55:53.467 # Opening port 6379: invalid bind address
```

When trying to start redis with `service redis start`. However, I confirmed that is nothing bound to port `6379` by running:

```
lsof -i :6379
```

I even rebooted the server just to make sure, but still getting invalid bind address. Running:

```
CentOS release 6.4
Redis 2.6.13
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: On what address is redis trying to bind? Check your redis.conf

Comment: That was it, was set to `localhost`, when I changed to `127.0.0.1` started working.

Comment: Check if the following entry exists in your `/etc/hosts` 127.0.0.1 localhost if you want to test with your original configuration

Answer (score 0):

Changed address binding from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/redis.conf` and it started working.

Comment: Is this problem solved? If so, please tap the outline of the tick mark so that it turns solid green. This will mark the issue as solved, so that it does not keep reappearing as an unanswered question.